Create Esri JavaScript web map and host on ArcGIS Online
I have created a relatively simple web map using Esri JavaScript. This web map has some widgets included on the map (SearchBar and some custom legends). I do not have access to an online server to host this web map, but would like to share it using my ArcGIS Online account if possible.
Is it possible to create a stand-alone Esri JavaScript Web Map and publish this webmap to ArcGIS Online as an ingestable web map?
